# Скрытый запуск скрипта powershell без отображения окна консоли

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-xp

Есть некоторый скрипт, который запускается через диспетчер задач Windows 7. Все работает без проблем, но так как некоторые операции производятся во время работы пользователя, то открывшееся окно консоли немного раздражает, да и пользователь может прервать работу скрипта, не дав ему корректно завершиться.

Отсюда вытекает вопрос: как запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме, чтобы он не мозолил глаза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, все просто. Достаточно добавить к выполнению задачи параметр:

```
- WindowStyle
        Установить значение для стиля окна: Normal, Minimized, Maximized или Hidden.
```

Answer (score 0):

Хочу немного дополнить ответ pincher1519. Нужно создать ярлык для ps1 скрипта  и в поле объект установить  powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -File "Путь до вашего ps1 "

Answer (score 0):

Вариант: воспользоваться утилитой [nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), создать ярлык и в поле "Объект" написать `nircmd execmd powershell <Путь к скрипту>`. Не забываем про безопасность - политика запуска скриптов, подписывание скриптов.
При использовании -WindowStyle Hidden окно всё же появляется на короткое время, а при использовании nircmd - нет.